# error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': Permission denied

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, pyaudio, portaudio

When trying to install pyaudio and apply the "python3 setup.py install" I get the following error

````
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/_portaudio.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': Permission denied```
````

Comment: The script attempted to install a shared library to a directory not owned by your current user. You may **try again with sudo, but it is unsafe** better install `portaudio` for current user using [conda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/portaudio) or `pip`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix it by packaging (dpkg) python with checkinstall, as I had not installed it the right way